# JPA Specification filter within an interval while ignoring days of month

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, filtering, specifications

I have table `paysheet` that contains monthYear values in this format :

08/2023
06/2023
05/2023

they're stored as strings in the database, i'm tasked to implement filtering using JPA specifications, i decided to create seperate columns for month+year, and transfer the old data there, keeping the month_year column like this :

```
ALTER TABLE paysheet
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS month INT,
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS year INT;

UPDATE paysheet
SET
    month = CAST(SPLIT_PART(month_year, '/', 1) AS INT),
    year = CAST(SPLIT_PART(month_year, '/', 2) AS INT);
```

here's my filtering logic :

I parse the monthYear strings "05/2023" to a YearMonth :

```
public static YearMonth parseMonthYear(String input) {
    return YearMonth.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yyyy"));
}
```

and then create my spec :

```
    YearMonth startDate = DateUtils.parseMonthYear(searchPaySheetDTO.getStartDate());
    YearMonth endDate = DateUtils.parseMonthYear(searchPaySheetDTO.getEndDate());
    Specification<Paysheet> specification = Specification
            .where(this.filterByStartInterval(startDate))
            .and(this.filterByEndInterval(endDate))
            .and(this.filterByCollaborator(collaborator));
```

there are my predicate builders ( for the dates ) :

```
private Specification<Paysheet> filterByStartInterval(YearMonth startDate) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("month"), startDate.getMonthValue()));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("year"), startDate.getYear()));

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}

private Specification<Paysheet> filterByEndInterval(YearMonth endDate) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("month"), endDate.getMonthValue()));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("year"), endDate.getYear()));

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```

clearly my logic is wrong, because this test case doesn't pass :

```
{
  "startDate": "09/2021",
  "endDate": "02/2026"
}
```

it does a `where month > 9 and month < 2` in sql which doesn't work.

I'm a bit stuck and will appreciate ur help.